# How to add a jumplist to a UWP Windows 10 app – written in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows-10, uwp, jump-list

I write Windows 10 Apps in JavaScript and know, there are some limitations. If I look at the [documentation for jumplists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplist?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1), Microsoft just writes »For information about creating or accessing this object, see Remarks.« for JavaScript and only gives examples for C#.

So how can I add a jumplist to my UWP Windows 10 App and how can I add and delete Listitems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very similar to the c# code.

You can find an example here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/JumpList/js/js

The essential code is:

```
var Uri = Windows.Foundation.Uri;
var StartScreen = Windows.UI.StartScreen;
var JumpList = StartScreen.JumpList;
var JumpListItem = StartScreen.JumpListItem;

var item = JumpListItem.createWithArguments("key", "caption");
item.description = "Description";
item.groupName = GroupName.value;
item.logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///images/your-images.png");
jumpList.items.append(item);

jumpList.saveAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What is the required build action of the .png file?